# Youth Christian sci-fi book trilogy featuring a telepathic man and woman, who're separated but find their way back to one another

Tags: story-identification, books, space, telepathy

I can't find these books for the life of me, and thought I'd give this a shot.

Looking for a sci-fi book trilogy I think I read in the early-to-mid-'90s. I think the main character was named "Wander (not 100% on this)." It's a love story between him and a female protagonist. They both have some kind of telepathic abilities.

There is a hegemony with tight control over the galaxy. One world secretly invested all their resources into super-powerful space fighters and set out to lead a rebellion.

The government secrets away all people with telepathic ability to enormous fortresses containing technology used to enhance the range at which telepathic ability can be used.

The two main characters are separated but somehow find their way back together. They fall in love. The rebellion succeeds.

There's a lot of emphasis on the technology used in the ships. They have some kind of energy lance that allows them to fly through enemy ships. I remember a quote in one of the books about the ship specifications that was something like, "You will die of old age before it runs out of power."

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

Comment: @LogicDictates - I think I read these in the early to mid 90s, and I believe it was a trilogy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If anyone correctly identifies the series you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. You can also leave comments to indicate if any answers posted are incorrect, so we know to keep looking.

Comment: @LogicDictates - thank you!